# ES6's export and curly braces

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I saw a code got posted in a chat channel. At the very end of his code is

```
export {UserInformation};
```

There were groups saying that the syntax is wrong. Some were saying it is fine as long as the variable exists.

So which group is right? It's my first time seeing this kind of syntax too. I've never seen curly braces in export. I've only used them in import. Like this

```
import {method} from 'someModule';
```

If I was writing it, I would write it as

```
export default UserInformation;
```

I don't want to pollute my brain with wrong information. Let me know which export is correct.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Or, as an alternative, you could read the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export. The very first example given is `export { name1, name2, …, nameN };`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The syntax is correct. This

```
export {UserInformation};
```

is shorthand for

```
export {UserInformation as UserInformation};
```

which is like doing

```
export const UserInformation = {};
```

when you define `UserInformation`.

It's useful to be able to export something from a module in a different place where it's defined (for readability, for instance).

In this case, you'd import `UserInformation` like this

```
import {UserInformation} from 'UserInformation.js';
```

Please note that `export default UserInformation;` is *not* equivalent to this. In that case, you're making `UserInformation` be the default module export. To import `UserInformation` in that case, you'd do:

```
import UserInformation from 'UserInformation.js';
```

which is shorthand for

```
import {default as UserInformation} from 'UserInformation.js';
```

[This blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) is an excellent read about the topic.

Comment: Your first example of `import UserInformation from 'UserInformation.js';` is wrong; it should be `import {UserInformation} from 'UserInformation.js';`. Your second example of importing the default is fine, but would normally be written as `import UserInformation from 'UserInformation.js';`.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you for catching that, just updated the answer. OP please take note of torazaburo's comment and the update to the answer, it was a big mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! :)