# Export function into hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component `useRandomizer` with random functions which I want to access inside main `App.js`

in `app.js` I have following hook:

```
import useRandomizer from './components/useRandomizer'
...

    useEffect(
        () => {
            let rndData = useRandomizer()
```

random component has following structure which gives me  error `React Hook "useRandomizer" cannot be called inside a callback.`

```
const useRandomizer = () => {       
    let rndData = []
    rndData.push(getRandomName())
    return rndData
}

export default useRandomizer
```

However if I retructure export like shown below, then these can be used in `app,js`

```
export default {
    getRandomName,
    ... other random functions
}
```

but this on the other hand give me more problems in `app.js` (code below). It runs ALL of random runction as many times as I've put any them. E.g get random name and random name two and random name three -> instead of pne array with 3 names it gives me 3 arrays with 3 names.

```
import useRandomizer from './components/useRandomizer'
...

    useEffect(
        () => {
            let rndData = []
            rndData.push(useRandomizer.getRandomName())
            rndData.push(useRandomizer.getRandomNameTwo())
            rndData.push(useRandomizer.getRandomNameThree())
```

---

edit1

this useEffect is a `dispatch` part of `useReducer` like this

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    ... do stuff
}
const [Dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, somestate)

useEffect(
    () => {
        Dispatch(somestate)
        let rndData = useRandomizer()
```

---

edit2

since reducer was concatenating arrays the goal was to push random values inside newly created ones. So instead of having a long code in `app.js` I've decided to move it into new component.

Comment: I'm confused, you're trying to run a `useEffect` inside a `useEffect`?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm trying to use function from a component which is located outside of `app.js` via import. There was a mistake, I've fixed the code `const function` inside `useEffect`

Comment: you are not returning from `useRandomizer `, return a string

Comment: what is the question? you want to get every render new name, and because of that you "decided to move it into new component"?

Comment: @LalitYadav fixed. thats an error. I'm returning an array whith data. It works well outside the `useEffect`

Comment: @Omer no, I had a bunch of rather similar functions like `function getRandomName()` `function getRandomNameTwo()` so I've packed then into one function that  pushes every random result into an array. Since they are long enough I've moved them into new component. They have nothing to do with render on their own. It is like having a component purely for `const` and purely for generating random values from functions.

Comment: @JayJayAbrams okay, you may want to refer to the conventions when using hooks to avoid ambiguous errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was using `export` without curly braces `{}`

So that's how my function has to look like:

```
const useRandomizer = () => {       
    let rndData = []
    rndData.push(getRandomName())
    return rndData
}

export default {useRandomizer} //was: export default useRandomizer
```

hence abovementioned `dispatch` code works fine now

```
import useRandomizer from './components/useRandomizer'
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    ... do stuff
}
const [Dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, somestate)

useEffect(
    () => {
        Dispatch(somestate)
        let rndData = useRandomizer()
```

Seems like adding `{}` drastically afftects import/export syntax.

[Here you can read more what exactly changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668861/es6s-export-and-curly-braces)